# Make Flip Card HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, bootstrap-5

I am new to HTML and want to make a specific element to flip. Now I created this [file](https://codepen.io/zenunbeh/pen/ExWveGO).

However, when the content, for the first element (see codepen) when it is flipped it is at the bottom (see picture). Can someone help that when the card is flipped, the content is at the top and not at the bottom as shown in the picture?[image]

```css
.services .icon-box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e2eefd;
  padding: 80px 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #f1f6fe;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #deebfd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon i {
  color: #3b8af2;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.services .icon-box h4 a {
  color: #222222;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box p {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.services .icon-box:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 25px 0 rgba(16, 110, 234, 0.1);
}

.services .icon-box:hover h4 a, .services .icon-box:hover .icon i {
  color: #106eea;
}

.services .icon-box:hover .icon {
  border-color: #106eea;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;

  height: 337px;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.flip-card:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="services" class="services">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nec aliquam metus, ac vehicula nibh. Nunc scelerisque tellus eu ullamcorper fermentum. Nam non condimentum lectus, vel dapibus leo. Integer elementum, elit id lacinia tempus, nisl augue accumsan est, nec lacinia libero eros non nulla. Pellentesque viverra eget lorem nec pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. .</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch flip-card" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box flip-card-inner" style="text-align: center;">
              <div class="flip-card-front">
                <div class="icon"><i class="bx bxl-dribbble"></i></div>
                <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.</p>
              </div>   
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-file"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-tachometer"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-world"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-slideshow"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Quis consequatur saepe eligendi voluptatem consequatur dolor consequuntur</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-arch"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplest** way it to just add `translateY` to the transform...

```
.flip-card-back {
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to position `.flip-card-back` absolutely - https://codepen.io/fromaline/pen/gOmxBGR?editors=0100

```
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Can you help me to make it center and not to much on the top?

Comment: @zenubeh, yeah. I've update code in codepen (link) and in answer itself to make text center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I added `.align-items-stretch:hover .flip-card-front` to `display: none;`

```css
.services .icon-box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e2eefd;
  padding: 80px 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #f1f6fe;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #deebfd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon i {
  color: #3b8af2;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.services .icon-box h4 a {
  color: #222222;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box p {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.services .icon-box:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 25px 0 rgba(16, 110, 234, 0.1);
}

.services .icon-box:hover h4 a, .services .icon-box:hover .icon i {
  color: #106eea;
}

.services .icon-box:hover .icon {
  border-color: #106eea;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
 
  height: 337px;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.align-items-stretch:hover .flip-card-front {
    display: none;
}
.flip-card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.flip-card:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="services" class="services">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nec aliquam metus, ac vehicula nibh. Nunc scelerisque tellus eu ullamcorper fermentum. Nam non condimentum lectus, vel dapibus leo. Integer elementum, elit id lacinia tempus, nisl augue accumsan est, nec lacinia libero eros non nulla. Pellentesque viverra eget lorem nec pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. .</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch flip-card" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box flip-card-inner" style="text-align: center;">
              <div class="flip-card-front">
                <div class="icon"><i class="bx bxl-dribbble"></i></div>
                <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur.</p>
              </div>   
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-file"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-tachometer"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-world"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-slideshow"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Quis consequatur saepe eligendi voluptatem consequatur dolor consequuntur</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-arch"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Lorem</a></h4>
              <p>Modi nostrum vel laborum. Porro fugit error sit minus sapiente sit aspernatur</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```